# Detecting QR code from an image with zxing

Tags: java, java-me, qr-code, zxing

Is zxing library will directly detect the QR code from an image without having to determine where the location of the QR code in the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

I wouldn't say "without having to determine" the location is entirely accurate, but the code location doesn't need to be provided to the library. The qrcode detector has various finder algorithms to detect the finder and alignment patterns in images. There are cases, of course, where it doesn't succeed.

Comment: Yeah exactly -- you don't have to know where the barcode is, but of course the library has to find it to do its work.